# Passing file path as a string from a dataframe column to readOGR function

Tags: r, dataframe, filepath, shapefile

I am trying to pass the file path of a shapefile to the function readOGR. The file path is a character string in a column of a dataframe. I am getting the following error: "Error in ogrListLayers(dsn = dsn) : Cannot open data source"

I have included sample code below:

```
#create dataframe
d <- data.frame("Species" = 1:2, "Shapefile.Path" = c("C:\\sample\\filename.shp","C:\\sample1\\filename1.shp"))

#convert class of Shapefile.Path to character
d$Shapefile.Path<-as.character(d$Shapefile.Path)

#print
d$file.name[1] 
#printed result: [1] "C:\\sample\\filename.shp"

#pass to readOGR
readOGR(d$Shapefile.Path[1])
```

As mentioned above, I am getting the following error after passing the file path to the readOGR function: "Error in ogrListLayers(dsn = dsn) : Cannot open data source"

What am I missing? Does the file path need to be enclosed in double quotes? How can I do this without including the double quotes as part of the character string?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried specifying only the folder name, without the file name?

Comment: I haven't tried that specifically, but when I use readOGR with the file path (including file name) it works. Ie readOGR("C:\\sample\\filename.shp") will load the file